# Error while building a simple project. Writes could not find the specified file

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

```
./project
      /site_ts
      /web
            Dockerfile
            requirements.txt
      docker-compose.yml
```

my `docker-compose.yml`:
version: '3'

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/site_ts
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /site_ts
WORKDIR /site_ts
COPY requirements.txt /site_ts/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /site_ts/
```

i write docker-compose up and take this `Error`:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 67, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 123, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 69, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 132, in get_project
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 188, in __init__
  File "site-packages\docker\api\client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The specified file cannot be found.')
[9356] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: This error not a Django, but Docker/Docker Compose error. Try first to validate that Docker installation is file by running `docker run -it --rm hello-world`

Comment: The problem is in your volume mapping. Host on the left, container on the right. Also, use copy, not add. And, you need a volumes entry at the end of the compose file too. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes